# sort float numbers as a natural numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a comma separated float numbers.

```
 var example = "1.1, 1.10, 1.2, 3.1, 3.14, 3.5";
```

and I want to sort this float numbers like,

```
"1.1, 1.2, 1.10, 3.1, 3.5, 3.14"
```

actually in my case, the numbers which are after decimals will consider as a natural numbers, so 1.2 will consider as '2' and 1.10 will consider as '10' thats why 1.2 will come first than 1.10.

and suggestion or example would be great for me, thanks.

Actually I want to first sort the array on the basis of numbers which are before decimals :) then the above logic will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with custom compare function, like so

```js
var example = "1.1, 1.10, 1.2, 3.1, 3.14, 3.5";

var res = example.split(',').sort(function (a, b) {
  var result;
  
  a = a.split('.'), 
  b = b.split('.');

  while (a.length) {
    result = a.shift() - (b.shift() || 0);
    
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return -b.length;
}).join(',');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom sort function that first compares the numerical value before the decimal point, and then compare the numerical value after the decimal point in case they are equal.

```
example.split(", ").sort(function (a, b) {
    var aParts = a.split(".", 2);
    var bParts = b.split(".", 2);
    if (aParts[0] < bParts[0]) return -1;
    if (aParts[0] > bParts[0]) return 1;
    return aParts[1] - bParts[1]; // sort only distinguishes < 0, = 0 or > 0
}).join(", ");
```

Comment: your example is working with 1 digit after decimals , not for more than 1 digits. here is your example implementation :) http://jsbin.com/qolapumaxa/1/edit

Comment: You should simply `console.log` the value of the above expression. I got `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.10, 2.11, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7`.

Comment: Of course, if your input can have multiple decimal points, e.g. `1.2.34`, then you should use the code from Alexander. But your initial question does not mention such a possibility.

Comment: Alan Tam, I shared the link, which have you example, and its not working 100%. anyways thanks :)

Comment: So you still don't understand what I have told you. You have to `console.log` the output of the expression I wrote. If you simply copy and paste it as is, of course it is not working!

Comment: Or prepend the first line with `example =` if you will 8)