# sort float numbers as a natural numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sql-server-2008-r2, natural-sort

Well I had asked the same question for jquery on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455928/sort-float-numbers-as-a-natural-numbers), Now my question is same with SQL Server Query :) But this time this is not comma separated, this is separate row in Database like

I have separated rows having float numbers.

```
Name
K1.1
K1.10
K1.2
K3.1
K3.14
K3.5
```

and I want to sort this float numbers like,

```
Name
K1.1
K1.2
K1.10
K3.1
K3.5
K3.14
```

actually in my case, the numbers which are after decimals will consider as a natural numbers, so 1.2 will consider as '2' and 1.10 will consider as '10' thats why 1.2 will come first than 1.10.

You can remove 'K' because it is almost common and suggestion or example would be great for me, thanks.

Comment: So you want to ORDER BY Kn as character, and then by decimal part as integer? Where are K11.1 placed?

Comment: Is Name column a varchar?

Comment: if you remove 'K', then it will be decimal number. and i want to sort the data on 2 combined condition. I want to first sort the data on the basis of numbers which are before decimals :) with the above logic. means sorted out should be "1.1, 1.2, 1.10, 3.1, 3.5, 3.14"

Comment: yes "Name" is the varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PARSENAME` (which is more of a hack) or String functions like `CHARINDEX` , `STUFF`, `LEFT` etc to achieve this.

**Input data**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 'K1.1' Name
UNION ALL SELECT 'K1.10'
UNION ALL SELECT 'K1.2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'K3.1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'K3.14'
UNION ALL SELECT 'K3.5'
)
```

**Using `PARSENAME`**

```
SELECT Name,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,'K',''),2),PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,'K',''),1)
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,'K',''),2)),
CONVERT(INT,PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,'K',''),1))
```

**Using String Functions**

```
SELECT Name,LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX('.',Name) - 1), STUFF(Name,1,CHARINDEX('.',Name),'')
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,REPLACE((LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX('.',Name) - 1)),'K','')),
CONVERT(INT,STUFF(Name,1,CHARINDEX('.',Name),''))
```

**Output**

```
K1.1    K1  1
K1.2    K1  2
K1.10   K1  10
K3.1    K3  1
K3.5    K3  5
K3.14   K3  14
```

Answer (score 2):

This works if there is always one char before the first number and the number is not higher than 9:

```
    SELECT name
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,2,1) AS INT), --Get the number before dot
CAST(RIGHT(name,LEN(name)-CHARINDEX('.',name)) AS INT) --Get the number after the dot
```

Comment: wait a min, if number will goes above to 9 then :( ?? please help.

Comment: Then the first term (get the number before dot) will get a little more complex - but with functions LEFT, RIGHT, CHARINDEX you will be able to parse the number between the letter and the dot.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, more verbal, but should do the trick

```
declare @source as table(num varchar(12));
insert into @source(num) values('K1.1'),('K1.10'),('K1.2'),('K3.1'),('K3.14'),('K3.5');

-- create helper table
with data as
(
    select num, 
           cast(SUBSTRING(replace(num, 'K', ''), 1, CHARINDEX('.', num) - 2) as int) as [first],
           cast(SUBSTRING(replace(num, 'K', ''), CHARINDEX('.', num), LEN(num)) as int) as [second]
    from @source
)
-- Select and order accordingly
select num
from data
order by [first], [second]
```

sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a9b06/2

Comment: Your solution is also working, let me run this on huge data :)

Answer (score -1):

The shorter solution is this one :

```
Select Num
from yourtable 
order by cast((Parsename(Num, 1) ) as Int)
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have a minus 1 one this answer :(